# sql date time validation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with datatype `nvarchar` and the column contains data i.e

```
2017-12,
2017-28,
2017-00,
0000,
0000-22
```

etc'.

So in the column I have invalid data i.e `2017-00`,`0000`,`0000-22`, so I want the column output should be valid data i.e `2017-12`,`2017-28` etc'. 
And use that column in join condition and case statements.

Comment: I'm not sure that `2017-12` stored as text should even be considered valid data.  Why are you not using date types for your date information?

Comment: And is this `2017-28` your valid date ? What date format you are following we can consider `28` as `day` only

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

Here i am doing the following.
1. First removing the - from your values
2. Since you said 2017-12,2017-28 is valid data that means year followed by date.
so they should fall between 2017-1 to 2017-31 i.e., 20171 and 207131 when the dash is removed.

Below query first remove the dash for your column then get the values which are between 20171 and 201731. In the query year is not hardcoded, so it works for next year also like 2018.

```
Select * from yourtable where REPLACE(yourcolumn, '-', '') 
between (year(getdate())+'1') AND (year(getdate())+'31')
```